# Problem on distributive lattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

As William Elliot noted, the initial statement was false. I changed it to a weaker one.

Let $L$ be a distributive lattice, denote $lu(x)$ - a least upper bound of elements which cover $x$ (to be clear: $y$ covers $x$ if $x < y$ and there is no element $z$ such that $x < z < y$), $gl(x)$ - a greatest lower bound of set of elements covered by $x$.

Prove (or disprove): let $x, y \in L$ such that $x \lor y = lu(x)$ (least upper bound of $x$ and $y$ equals to $lu(x)$). Then $gl(y) \le x$. Would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: That is false.  x = 0 with cover 1 and y = 2.  Also x v y is not the upper bound of x and y, it is the least upper bound of x and y.  Upper x is bad notation as it confuses with the upper set of x.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this. You are right. I changed the initial statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the lattice is a complete lattice because the covers of an element may be an infinite set.  There is a counter example.

Consider the complete distributive lattice [0,1].
There are no covers of 1.
So the least upper bound of the covers is 0.
As 0 does not cover any element
the greatest lower bound of the elements 0 covers is 1.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, it seems that my statement again is incorrect... But there are finite lattices with this property (with exception of going from 1 to 0) (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Distributive_lattice_example.svg), just can't figure the common criteria for them.